# How to use fullcalendar addeventsource with array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fullcalendar

Can you please say whats wrong with this? I have a javascript function called which creates a new events array and tries to refresh fullcalendar.

var events=new Array();
      var numberofevents = this.serviceVariableGetDates.getTotal();

```
  for (i=0;i<numberofevents;i++)
       {
       //alert("numbrr:" + i);
       var dates=this.serviceVariableGetDates.getItem(i);
       console.log(dates.getData());
       var start_date = dates.getValue("c0");
       var end_date = dates.getValue("c1");
       var event_name = dates.getValue("c2");
       //var EventEntry = [ 'title: '+ event_name, 'start: '+ start_date,'end: '+ end_date ];
       events['title'] = event_name;
       events['start'] = start_date;
       events['end'] = end_date;
       events['color'] = "blue";
       this.label1.setCaption(start_date);
       //EventArray.push(EventEntry);
       console.log(events['title']);
       }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',events);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

The calendar does not refresh or show the events in  the events array....Through different debug methods I am sure that the events array is populated with the correct data. The start_date is for example "1307318400000" which is in the unix timestamp format. The fullcalendar is being initialized somewhere else in the begining (when the page load) and it stays unchanged even though addeventsource and rerenderevents methods are called.

Comment: Rendering the event feed as an array is not recommended- Even the author talk about this and encourages server side feed using json replies. Managing the arrays on the client can be very difficult. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/

Answer (score 4):

according to the docs you need to put array of events to the addEventSource function

> event must be an [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) with a title and start at the very
>   least.

```
var events=new Array();
var numberofevents = this.serviceVariableGetDates.getTotal();
    for (i=0;i<numberofevents;i++)
    {
    //alert("numbrr:" + i);
    var dates=this.serviceVariableGetDates.getItem(i);
    console.log(dates.getData());
    var start_date = dates.getValue("c0");
    var end_date = dates.getValue("c1");
    var event_name = dates.getValue("c2");
    //var EventEntry = [ 'title: '+ event_name, 'start: '+ start_date,'end: '+ end_date ];
    event = new Object();       
    event.title = event_name; // this should be string
    event.start = start_date; // this should be date object
    event.end = end_date; // this should be date object
    event.color = "blue";
    event.allDay = false;
    this.label1.setCaption(start_date);
    //EventArray.push(EventEntry);
    console.log(events['title']);
    events.push(event);
    }
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',events);
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

Hope this will help!