# Converting json text encoded from php multidimensional array into a json object for fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar to display events. What I need to do is convert text that is returned via an ajax call to a json object and then use `$('#calendar').Fullcalendar('addEventSource', json object)`. The text that is returning is as follows:

```
[
  {"id":"1","title":"ECNG 1015\nENG4\nK. John","start":"8:00 am","end":"10:00 am","allDay":false},
  {"id":"2","title":"ECNG 1016\nENG7\nP. Weiss","start":"1:00 pm","end":"2:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"3","title":"ECNG 2017\nENG6\nK. John","start":"10:00 am","end":"12:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"4","title":"ECNG 1018\nENG6\nF. Philbert","start":"4:00 pm","end":"5:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"5","title":"ECNG 1019\nLT4\nJ. Jerremy","start":"2:00 pm","end":"4:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"6","title":"ECNG 1020\nLT4\nV. Victor","start":"5:00 pm","end":"7:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"7","title":"ECNG 1019\nLT4\nJ. Jerremy","start":"1:00 pm","end":"3:00 pm","allDay":false},
  {"id":"8","title":"ECNG 1017\nENG5\nL. Lawrence","start":"9:00 am","end":"10:00 am","allDay":false},
  {"id":"9","title":"ECNG 2017\nENG6\nK. John","start":"10:00 am","end":"12:00 pm","allDay":false}
]
```

Which is encoded from a multidimensional array in PHP. I am having no luck converting this text into a json object. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: what you mean about json object in this code `$('#calendar').Fullcalendar('addEventSource', json object)`, in your json response is using JSONArray with value of json object so you have 9 json object, what do you want to ?can you tell more details again..?

Comment: could you please tell us more, about your problem with the json object? Why do you think you can't convert them? whats the error message, etc...

Comment: I was encountering a problem using fullcalendar's addEventSource method with a json string. However after looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182822/how-to-use-fullcalendar-addeventsource-with-array/6988239#6988239) solution along with using the [jsdate](http://www.datejs.com/) library to parse the date string I was able to get the events to display.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying [JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: i do not see how this could help him to convert it in javascript?